# Where is /etc/sysconfig/zabbix-server on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, oracle11g, ubuntu-18.04, zabbix

so I was trying to make monitoring oracle database by ODBC using Zabbix, I follow some step [from this Github](https://git.zabbix.com/projects/ZBX/repos/zabbix/browse/templates/db/oracle_odbc)

my Zabbix was on Ubuntu 18.04 and **I can't find /etc/sysconfig**, i was going to make zabbix-server for this code :

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/19.6/client64 
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/usr/lib64:/usr/lib:$ORACLE_HOME/bin 
export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
```

but I find zabbix-server in **/etc/init.d/zabbix-server**, is it the same from **/etc/sysconfig/zabbix-server**?

Comment: Oracle is not supported on Ubuntu and trying to get it to run involves applying lots of hacks and work-arounds. You would be better to install Oracle Linux (or any other supported OS) inside a virtual machine and run Oracle on that.

Comment: @MT0 so instead I installed it directly on Zabbix server, I could installed it on another OS Linux with Zabbix proxy right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the file, and reference it inside of systemd unit. See for example:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161901/systemctl-service-cant-read-the-environment-variable
- https://serverfault.com/questions/413397/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-systemd-service

The files `/etc/init.d/zabbix-server` and `/etc/sysconfig/zabbix-server` are completely different, and should never be mixed.